# How to find out why/where Symfony sets PHPSESSID cookie?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am running a `Symfony 2.8` based webpage which is separated into a public and a private part (login required).

Due to the "new" GDPR regulation in Europe I have checked which cookies my page actually use. Since I do not use any analytics or tracking tools are related stuff, the public part of the web page does actually need any cookies. However, when inspecting the page with Firefox Webmaster Tools I see that the `PHPSESSID` Cookie is set when visiting the public pages.

My code of the public pages does not actively uses the session (at least not that I am aware of). Sure the session needs to be queried to check if the user is logged in, is this enough to create a session if it does not exists? I suspect that some third party code/bundle might query the session and thus set the cookie.

Is there a way to find out where and why the cookie is set by symfony?

Comment: "My code does not actively uses the session". So, you login everytime you visit private part?

Comment: I have changed this to "My code of the public pages...". Sure a cookie is used to remember the logged in user...

Comment: There are certain features that will cause a session to be started. For example do you use forms with csrf_tokens?

Comment: When it comes to GDPR, your PHP session cookie is what you call a functional cookie, ie. it is required for your site to run. even on systems were you decline all cookies, functional cookies will still be used. the ones you need to ask peremission for are tracking/analytics cookies, and 3rd party/advertising cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, php starts session when session_start() happens  but it depends on php.ini settings. Symfony starts session dynamically when you first time try to do something with it.
I had the same problem few days ago. In my case symfony starts session when tries to get user token from session.
What I recommend to do: check what session handler you are using, then make a breakpoint inside it and debug. 
By default (and in my case) session starts at  NativeSessionStorage start method.